# OpenCV3, SIFT compute with vector<vector<KeyPoint>>

Tags: opencv, c++11, opencv3.0, sift

According to the document, SIFT object could use the function below to compute descriptors for multiple images:

> virtual void compute (InputArrayOfArrays images, std::vector< std::vector< KeyPoint > > &keypoints, OutputArrayOfArrays descriptors)

I'm trying to compute the SIFT descriptors for multiple images with the code below:

```
Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
vector<vector<KeyPoint>> train_keypoints;
f2d->detect(train_imgs, train_keypoints);

vector<Mat> train_descriptors;
f2d->compute(train_imgs, train_keypoints, train_descriptors);
```

It could be compiled under Mac OS 10.10.5 with opencv3, while it might terminate during execution with error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector

Or I could change the type of train_descriptors into Mat **(instead of vector< Mat >)**, it'll still fail during execution with another error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_descriptors.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT) in compute, file /tmp/opencv320151228-32931-2p5ggk/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp, line 126 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv320151228-32931-2p5ggk/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp:126: error: (-215) _descriptors.kind() == _InputArray::STD_VECTOR_MAT in function compute

**What type of train_descriptors** should I use to make this code compile and run correctly?

---

Could anyone told me what's the difference between **vector< Mat >** and **OutputArrayOfArrays**?

Comment: What is `train_imgs`? The code works correcly for me if `train_imgs` is a `vector<Mat>`. Btw, your answer below is quite wrong.

Comment: THX man. When train_imgs is an obj of Mat, it fails. After I change it into vector<Mat>, it works. Could you pls tell me what's the difference between vector< Mat > and OutputArrayOfArrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
vector<vector<KeyPoint>> train_keypoints;
f2d->detect(train_imgs, train_keypoints);

vector<Mat> train_descriptors;
f2d->compute(train_imgs, train_keypoints, train_descriptors);
```

works well if `train_imgs` is a `vector<Mat>`.

---

You don't need to create a vector of 50000 elements, simply use `vector<Mat> train_descriptors;`.

---

`OutputArrayOfArrays`, like `InputArray`, `OutputArray` and the like, are an abstraction layer that OpenCV uses to allow to pass to a function both `cv::Mat` and `std::vector`. **You should never use these classes explicitly.** From [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d32/classcv_1_1__InputArray.html#details):

> The class is designed solely for passing parameters. That is, normally you should not declare class members, local and global variables of this type.

Also, note that `OutputArrayOfArrays` is just a typedef of `OutputArray`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code could work I guess:

```
Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
vector<vector<KeyPoint>> train_keypoints;
f2d->detect(train_imgs, train_keypoints);

vector<Mat> train_descriptors = vector<Mat>(5e4);
f2d->compute(train_imgs, train_keypoints, train_descriptors);
```